# Estimate probability that two random integers between 0 and k are relatively prime

Tags: python, primes

By generating and checking p random pairs.

Somewhat confused on how to go about doing this. I know I could make an algorithm that determines whether or not two integers are relatively prime. I am also having difficulty understanding what generating and checking p random pairs means.

Comment: Lets say `k=9` and `p=3`. Then maybe you randomly end up with `(1,9)`, `(2,8)`, `(6,5)`, and those are your `p=3` pairs?

Comment: The question is about checking whether or not two integers are relatively prime or about generating p random pairs?

Comment: You may also want to know how many possible pairs you can get, and how many of those are relatively prime, then you have a proportion.

Comment: Your result should converge on `(6 / pi^2)` fairly quickly as k increases.

Answer (score 3):

Without a complete enumeration of the relative primeness of all numbers between 0 and k (a huge task and one that grows as the square of k) you can make an estimate by selecting a relatively large number of random pairs (p of them) and determine whether they are relatively prime.

The assumption is that as the sample size increases the proportion of relative primes tends towards the required probability value (*i.e.* if you take 10,000 sampled pairs and you find that 7,500 of them are relatively prime then you'd estimate the probability of relative primeness at 0.75).

in Python `random.randint(0, k)` selects a (pseudo-)random integer between `0` and `k`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random as rs
p = ? # Put in your value here
k = ? # put in range value here

lst = []
for i in range(p):
  lst.append([rs.randint(0, k), rs.randint(0, k)])

# Now loop over lst and find how many pairs are relatively prime (count)
prob = count/p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint


def gcd(a, b):
    return gcd(b, a % b) if b else a # Euclid's algorithm

def is_coprime(a, b):
  return gcd(a, b) == 1

def get_coprime_prob(k, runs=1000):
  count = sum(1 for _ in range(runs) if is_coprime(randint(0, k), randint(0, k)))
  return count / float(runs)
```